# Schema.org Product type has no property price?

Tags: product, schema.org

I have a webshop. On the product detail pages I use the `Product` type from schema.org: http://schema.org/Product

It supports the properties `name`, `description`, `image` and `url`.

However, it does not seem to support the inclusion of a "price" property, based on for example https://schema.org/price

I find it weird that the `Product` definition does not seem to support a price. Or am I using the wrong type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [`price` property](http://schema.org/price) is not defined for the [`Product` type](http://schema.org/Product).

You might want to use the [`Offer` type](http://schema.org/Offer). Either

- on its own (instead of `Product`), or
- in combination with `Product` (related via [`offers`](http://schema.org/offers)/[`itemOffered`](http://schema.org/itemOffered)).